# Reader and Writer Methods

Tags: ruby, class, methods

Who can explain me the code snippets of "def name" and "def name=()"?
I don't understand why it is defined 2 times.

```
class Bird < Animal
  def initialize(name, length)
    @name
    @length
  end

  def name
    @name
  end

  def name=(new_name)
    @name = new_name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are getter and setter methods

```
bird = Bird.new("pigeon", length)
 => #<Bird:0x007f93e9b41278> 
bird.name
 => "pigeon" 
bird.name = 'seagull'
 => "seagull" 
bird.name
 => "seagull"
```

Both of the methods you defined in the class are what's being called here - the call to

```
bird.name = 'seagull'
```

is actually syntactic sugar for the method call

```
bird.name=('seagull')
```

Of course, the most "rubyish" way to write these methods would be one call to attr_accessor:

```
class Bird < Animal
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name, length)
    @name = name
    @length = length
  end
end
```

This will give you both the getter and setter methods for the name attribute

Comment: Buf... Many alternatives methods has ruby... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One returns a value, one sets a value. Look at the method bodies.

```
def name
  @name               # return @name
end

def name=(new_name)
  @name = new_name    # set @name to your argument
end
```

Also, your initialize method does nothing. I assume you want to set those variables to the arguments you are taking.

```
def initialize(name, length)
    @name, @length = name, length
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why it is defined 2 times.

`def name` to read value from `@name` and `def name=` to write value to `@name`.

The below is a *reader*(attr_reader) method

```
def name; @name; end # shortcut is attr_reader :name
```

The below is a *writer*(attr_writer) method

```
def name=(new_name) ;  @name = new_name ; end # shortcut is attr_writer :name
```

A very good documentation [**What is an accessor?**](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html)

Answer (score 0):

These methods are known as "getters" and "setters", because (unsurprisingly), they 'get' or 'set' a variable.
You can also think of one as a 'command,' which will make some change to the data, and one as a 'query,' which will simply report a value (this is a helpful distinction to keep in mind when you are designing your own methods as well).

Ruby includes three class methods that define these getters and setters for you: `attr_reader` defines the getter, `attr_writer` defines the setter, and `attr_accessor` defines both.

You could just interact directly with the instance variable, but in most situations, code is easier to change and reason about when you use methods to access data rather than messing with the data itself.